# url gets appended in href

Tags: xslt

-->

Now the page path gets appended to the externalurl value like:

http://www.site.com/pages/www.externalurl.com

I just want to set www.externalurl.com to the href. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to set a default `@href`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:if test="not(contains(externalurl, '://'))">http://</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="externalurl" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now what about if external url already had http://? I just need to get rid of the page path.

Comment: @SajmiraZ: If the externalurl already contains the `http://` then you don't include another one, of course. See changed answer.